# Can the iPhone 5S physically support iOS 13.0?

Tags: iphone, ios

My iPhone 5S has 16GB of data with 9.7GB used.

Is it possible for the [iOS 13.0 to run successfully](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210393) on it?

Comment: One question, per question please. Side loading an unsigned OS is a valid question to ask, so let’s have that properly asked and answered if the “no” answer here isn’t sufficient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No version of iOS 13 will install or run for that phone.

Wikipedia is reliable for this kind of information, and it says the iPhone 5S only supports [iOS 7 through 12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_5S). See also [this answer](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252633538) which has Apple's stamp of approval.

You can't sideload iOS, and even if you could, iOS 13 wouldn't work since it doesn't run on the [A7 processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_A7) which the iPhone 5S has.